# queue to handle update queries to sqlite with out using threads?

Tags: database, performance, sqlite

I have a project in which many applications will send update queries to a DB handler. These updates are to be maintained in a queue and updated to sqlite db. Is the any good practice to improve the performance of the system without any effect to data persistence in db? And what happens if there is a system crash?

Comment: write it a to a file (log file or sql file) and then import it in DB. Db import feature can help you in this.

Comment: If you are using java then DB chaining classes are present which can help you queue update statements and execute it in bulk on DB to avoid large no. of concurrent connections to DB. If you need more details let me know I'll explain it in answer

Comment: Writing it to a file is not a solution as sqlite is a db in a disk file and it almost same. And if i execute in bulk i would lose a bulk of data if there is a system crash.

Comment: how will you lose the data if you are writing it to a file on disk which is persistent. what do you mean by system crash and I didn't get "Writing it to a file is not a solution as sqlite is a db in a disk file and it almost same". could you elaborate more your question and need?

Comment: sqlite db is application oriented. So it maintain the db as a disk file. If we try to write to a secondary memory that takes almost same cost as executing the query in sqlite. And i meant the abrupt power off of system due to load issue,heating up or due to any unexpected reasons where the os will not have control to backup or perform counter measures.

Comment: @NachiketKate can you explain me the java chaining classes?